# How to generate .xap files in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight application with 2 pages, first is "animation" and second is "transformation"

first page works well, but second display nothing and i think the problem is: i don't have any transformation.xap. I only have have the animation.xap in my "clientBin" data for some reason

So here is my question: can i generate a .xap file for my transformation page so it can works?

Comment: You should only have one xap per project, not per 'page' (whatever that is). Are your 'animation' and 'transformation' pages in different visual studio projects?

Answer (score 0):

Both pages are stored withing the same Silverlight application.

If you want to switch between pages you'll need to either:

1. Create another project that contains the transformation page and
   redirect the browser to the page hosting it
2. Switch pages by setting the application's RootVisual to the page you want displayed